# datetimepicker is not displaying the saved value during edit

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

I encountered a problem in my datetimepicker. It is not displaying the saved value from database during Edit mode [(see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlmJl.png). The datetimepicker must disable past dates and to do this,

i have this javascript code,

```
<script>
  $(function () {
   $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
       minDate: new Date()
     });
});
</script>
```

Past dates are already disabled but the saved value of datetimepicker is not displaying when I edit the data.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: where do you pass the value from the database to the datetimepicker control?

Comment: @jamiedanq, this is my code to get the value from database.. Html.EditorFor(model => model.Created_Date_Time)                       
                                <script>
                                        $(function () {
                                            $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
                                                minDate: new Date()
                                            });
                                        });
                                    </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialise the datetimepicker component with the data you are bringing from the database.

```
 $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
 minDate: new Date(),
 date: ToDate });
```

where `ToDate` will be the date you are getting from the database.

You can find an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Jibin/0Ltv25o8/5284/)

In the example I have hardcoded the date value,you have to pass the value which you are getting from the database.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i tried this one, still no value displayed.. this is the code I use now.. @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Created_Date_Time)                                                                          
           <script>
                                        $(function () {
                                            $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
                                                minDate: new Date()
                                            });
                                        });
                                    </script>

Comment: This code disables the past dates in datetimepicker but not retrieving the value from database. I need to disable the past dates and retrieve the value on database as well..

Comment: thank you for the answer.. the datetimepicker is now displaying the saved value from database but now, I can't click the button to display the datetimepicker. :(

Comment: here is my code..<div class="col-md-6 input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Created_Date_Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>   
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
date: Model.Created_Date_Time,
 minDate: new Date()
});
  });
</script>

Comment: Thank you. I already tried but the first problem I encountered persist, still it doesn't display the saved value, only the disabled dates is ok.

Comment: Try changing model to Model. Something like this `<div class="col-md-6 input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Created_Date_Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })<span class="input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> </span> </div> <script type="text/javascript"> $(function () { $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({  minDate: new Date() }); }); </script>`

Comment: Hi Sir. Already found the answer. Thank you so much for your help. This is my code... <script>
                                    $(function () {
                                        $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
                                            minDate: '@Model.Created_Date_Time'
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>

Answer (score 0):

Already found the solution. Thank you so much for your help.

```
<script>
   $(function () {
      $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
         minDate: '@Model.Created_Date_Time'
       });
   });
</script>
```